# Use DNS for fast IP switching

Tags: domain-name-system, load-balancing

We own two different servers with different IP addresses. We are using one server as the main one which runs mainly Nginx to serve application for both 80 and 443, and the second one as a backup in case something wrong happens. Then there is AWS load balancer which purpose is to switch the IP address of the main server as fast as possible using AWS-CLI - this load balancer is then used as CNAME for our domain.

My question is: How can I achieve the same thing without using an overpriced AWS Load Balancer? Is there any way to change the A record of a domain without downtime?

I thought I would use Nginx as Load Balancer on a different server so I have only one IP Address to add as A record and then change the IP of the main server directly in Nginx configuration and reload Nginx configuration. I'm not sure if this is a reliable solution?

Answer (score 0):

As painful as it can be to setup and diagnose, this is what the notion of GSLB (Global Server Load Balancing) is designed for. This is what the likes of Amazon Route 53 does for you.

Plenty of decent material out there; I won't confuse you by trying to distill it into this answer.

I don't have an experience of any open-source solutions for managing GSLB, but there is at least [Polaris-GSLB, which is apparently decent](https://github.com/polaris-gslb/polaris-gslb/wiki/Overview). You do need to have some mechanism for sharing health/metric data between the sites and deciding on failover at an internet scale and with internet latencies. This tends to be propriatary as far as I know. I do know from personal experience you have to be very fastidious (ie. automate or die from frustration) with making sure everything is setup (nothing is missing, both sides are congruent).

However, GSLB is the Enterprise grade solution to this. For smaller sites, you *could* just get away with something that uses various DNS provider APIs to change it when it detects an outage. You'd want to make something that tests from different locations though. Then if your collective service test fails, you could have it maybe fire a webhook to something that adjusts the DNS. Plenty of duct-tape on that roll.